# Plot area reduces when x title includes superscript

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, axis, superscript

I'm drawing a figure with two plots:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(y= 1:20, x= sample(1:5, 20, replace= T))
A <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() + labs(x= 'A (kg/mm^3)', y= 'B (%)')
B <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() + labs(y= 'A (mm^2)', x= 'B (%)')
ggarrange(A, B)
```

When I include in one of the plots a superscript (in either the x or the y axis) the area of the plot reduces automatically a bit.

```
C <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() + labs(x= expression(paste(paste("A (kg/", mm^3), ')')), y= expression('B (%)', c^2))
D <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() + labs(y= expression(paste('A', mm^2)), x= expression('B (%)', c^2))
ggarrange(C, D)
```

I tried to reduce the area of the plot without a superscript by adding an expression that includes an invisible superscript (`c^2`) but the undesired area-reduction does not disappear.

Comment: If you want the plot areas exactly the same size because you are plotting them in a 'grid', perhaps `library(cowplot); plot_grid(A, B, C, D, nrow = 2, align = "vh")` would suffice?

Answer (score 1):

For plot composition, package 'patchwork' is the best and easiest to use. It automatically aligns and resizes the plotting areas.

```r
library(patchwork)

C | D
```

[image]